# Set both inset and outset box shadow using CSS

Tags: css

The `box-shadow` property has a property value called `inset`, so the shadow can be *inset*, or *outset*.

But how is it possible, to set both *inset*, and *outset* shadow for a `div` in CSS?

Comment: It should be noted that there is no such value as `outset`. Either `inset` is specified or it defaults back to an outset-style shadow. For example, the following declaration *still* results in an `inset` appearance: `box-shadow: inset 8px 8px; box-shadow: outset 8px 8px;` because `outset` is not valid. Instead, `box-shadow: 8px 8px;` must be used (omitting `inset`). `box-shadow` must be redefined in its entirety, because there is no dedicated property for defining *only* the inset/outset appearance.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You need to separate them using a `,`

```css
div {
  margin: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px tomato, 0 0 5px black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Uz6Ku/)</kbd>

<kbd>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Uz6Ku/1/)</kbd> *(Nothing different, but used `white` `border` for better indication)*

So here in the above example, it sets the shadow *inset* with the `tomato` color, and the  other set of rules separated using a comma is for *outset* i.e `black` shadow

Comment: But what if you want to apply the inset shadow through one class, and the outset shadow through another class? If I use wo different classes, one for the inset and the other one for the outset, the second class will just override the first one.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use comma to separate both shadows.

```
div{
    top: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px grey, 0 0 10px black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
}
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J8CK3/1/)